# Chain Complex morphism: Arbitrary maps instead of Homomorphism?

Tags: homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, exact-sequence, abelian-categories

Given two chain complexes $\{ G_i \}$ and $\{ H_i \}$ we usually define a *morphism* of chain complex as a family of **homormophisms** $\{ f_i \}$ such that the diagram commutes:

$$
\begin{matrix}
\dots &\xrightarrow{\partial} & G_n &\xrightarrow{\partial} &G_{n-1} &\xrightarrow{\partial} &G_{n-2} &\xrightarrow{\partial} & \dots \\
\dots& & f_n \downarrow & &f_{n-1}\downarrow & & f_{n_2} \downarrow & &\dots \\
\dots &\xrightarrow{\partial} & H_n &\xrightarrow{\partial} &H_{n-1} &\xrightarrow{\partial} &H_{n-2} &\xrightarrow{\partial} & \dots \\
\end{matrix}
$$

If we weaken the condition that $\{ f_i \}$ are simply **maps** [That is, they are any function $f_i: G_i \rightarrow H_i$ such that the diagram commutes] what happens? Formally, the maps $\{ f_i \}$ are such that $\partial^H \circ f_n = f_{n-1} \circ \partial^G$. In this case, can we **recover a theory of homology**?

Clearly, such maps can be arbitrarily bad. For example, consider:

\begin{matrix}
\mathbb Z &\xrightarrow{\times 2} &\mathbb Z \\
f \downarrow & & g \downarrow \\
\mathbb Z &\xrightarrow{\times 3} &\mathbb Z \\
\end{matrix}

$$
f(x) \equiv \begin{cases} 1 & x = 1 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases} \quad
g(x) \equiv \begin{cases} 3 & \text{x = 2} \\ 0 &\text{otherwise}\end{cases}
$$

This diagram commutes by chasing elements:

\begin{bmatrix}
1 & \xrightarrow{\times 2}& 2 \\
\downarrow f&   & \downarrow g \\
1 & \xrightarrow{\times 3} &3
\end{bmatrix}

\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha \neq 1 & \xrightarrow{\times 2}& \beta \neq 2 \\
\downarrow f&   & \downarrow g \\
0 & \xrightarrow{\times 3} & 0
\end{bmatrix}

However, **can we still salvage the theory** and get a notion of a long exact sequence of Homology from arbitrary maps? Or is this the reason why we ask for homorphisms: So that we can build the theory of Snake lemma which we parlay into the long exact sequence of Homology? If it's not possible to salvage, is there some way to *prove* that this cannot lead to a useful theory?

Comment: What do you understand by $\text{ equivariant map}$ ? Are your examples $f,g$ equivariant maps ?

Comment: Yes. Am I abusing terminology here? For me, an equivariant map is a map that allows the diagram to commute, nothing more.

Comment: oh!,I see. The correct definition is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivariant_map).

Comment: Thanks for the correction! I was using the terminology I learnt from representation theory; I had forgotten that we tacitly assume that the equivariant maps are _linear_ in that setting.

Comment: in order to get something like cohomology you need some eventual vanishing of the ds, however one can weaken it, you might want to inform yourself on $N$-complexes or $p$-complexes

Comment: @Enkidu  I am confused. The $ds$ (on in this case, the $\partial$s since I have homology) already cause terms to vanish since $\partial \circ \partial = 0$, as I asked that $\{ G_i \}$ and $\{ H_i \}$ are chain complexes?

Comment: What would be the motivation behind such maps ?

Comment: ah sorry overread that, If you just take maps it will get tricky however, since all your objects are pointed it could work out, but since essentially the LES is an inductive snake lemma you in my opinion should not immediately pass to just maps and maybe look for an abelian super cat, like abelian groups, then you would get a long exact sequence, however you would have to also take the cohomology wrt that cat, but assuming your cat admits a forgetful functor to abelian groups that should not be a problem

Comment: @MaximeRamzi I am trying to understand whether the maps $\{ f_i \}$ being homomorphisms is somehow essential to the theory of homology. I'm trying to weaken the axioms to see what doesn't work, so I get a feel for what _does_ work.

Comment: You want the chain maps to induce maps between the corresponding homologies. There is no reason to expect this is possible if the maps aren't homomorphisms.

Comment: @Enkidu can you expand your comment into an answer? I have not studied the 'super-general' version of homology phrased in the language of abelian categories.

Comment: @Thorgott Indeed, there is no reason to expect this. But there is no reason to expect homology works at all! Most of this machinery is miraculous; I'm trying to see how far we can push it. Can you furnish a _proof_ that taking arbitrary maps somehow creates an obstacle to building a homology theory?

Comment: Well it *is* essential wrt to the usage of homology. Now maybe you had other uses in mind, hence my question. Or maybe you can give an example of a naturally arising situation where you get maps that aren't morphisms (you gave an example but I wouldn't exactly qualify it as natural)

Comment: Well, I think that your weakened chain maps do not necessarily induce maps between these homologies is a very essential obstruction to building homology theory. This alone will make a long exact homology sequence fail, even without considering the snake lemma (which is usually the non-trivial part of the sequence).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested,

if you want to drop requirements on the maps inducind a morphism of chaincomplexes, you are actually passing into a bigger category while considering the chaincomplexes also just as these more general objects, so something like: Vectorspaces are just special abelian groups.

However, this category will need to have the structure to allow the following:

1. defining chaincomplexes: you need to be able to say $d^2=0$ so you need a $0$ and in particular a pointed cat
2. defining homology: In general homology is the cokernel of the kernel map of the differential, so you will have to consider a more general category that admits at least that.
3. Furthermore, in order to get a long exact sequence you need the snake lemma which you may impose as a condition, but I guess you actually dont want that but actually you just need to consider the category to be abelian.

However all of this structural requirements are very well described in Weibel.

Considering that the embedding of your subcategory should induce something on the derived category, but be aware that sometimes dropping requirements can do more damage than help.

Furthermore, I am sorry if this is not precise enough, but to really work all of that out properly in details I would have to write 2-6 hours.

Comment: Thank you for the references to the book (Weibel). I'll check this out!

Comment: for example, passing from the category of modules over a $k$-algebra to the category of vectorspaces you lose a lot more structure as you will not be able to reconstruct the module structure of the homology and homology of vectorspaces tends to be very boring